# Cut off Cucumber Vines

Tags: plant-care

One of the vines on one of my cucumber plants got cut off.  Can I plant the cut off vine?  It has small cucumbers on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try. Odds are not great it will work, but odds are zero that it will work if you don't try it.

Comment: Evidently it's actually pretty common for shorter sections (rooting offshoots to make new plants) and that might work better than trying to support a whole vine (assuming some considerable length) before it manages to make roots. Rooting hormone is advised.